# Block a computer from all but 1 or 2 websites?

Tags: networking, whitelist, block

I'm setting up a computer for our machine shop that is intended for them to only get to a couple sites they may need while working. It needs to still be on our network so they can look at files saved on the network, but it shouldn't be able to get to any non-white-listed sites. Are there any easy ways to do this?

Comment: Read about Network Proxy!

Comment: Depends on waht you have in place.

Answer (score 0):

Use a firewall, such as sonicwall,watchguard,fortinet,cisco,paloalto,etc... they will come with a deny all by default and then you can whitelist the port and ip of the sites you wish for them to access. Make sure that you're routing all your traffic through that firewall.

Comment: If, for some reason, you are unable to bring an edge firewall into the mix, consider the onboard firewall for the OS (windows firewall, IPTables)

Comment: Will a firewall allow me to select which users are blocked? It seems they'd like to have some people be able to sign in with full access, but have a generic "Worker login" that everyone else logins into and then lets them go to their one site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Squid proxy, it runs on ubuntu and can be integrated into active directory. Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRx_RkdvpS4

Just set your clients up with the proxy and set the ACL's